# What are Film Reels in LA Noire?

Tags: la-noire

I'm over 60% done with the game but I still have 0/50 "Film Reels" (as shown in the Statistics page).  What / Where are Film Reels?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Film Reels are well-hidden collectibles, that are scattered around the game. 
[image: This is what you are looking for]
What you are looking for

You could spend hours and hours of searching and looking the 50 reels, or you could use [this guide](http://www.thehdroom.com/news/L.A.-Noire-Gold-Film-Reels-Locations-Guide/9022) that shows the location of all the films.

Answer (score 6):

They are the hidden collectibles.

You can find a map of them here. http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/lan/checklist.html

Answer (score 3):

Film reels are little golden circles (film reels, more or less!) that you can find in various locations scattered around the city.  If you can, login to [Rockstar Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/), and there's an interactive map to all of them (along with every other pickup in the game, practically) you can use.  I know on consoles, the map is tied to your save game, so it will further tell you where the ones you're missing are.